# Redirect Java 8 GC logs to stderr

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there any way to print GC logs to stderr instead of stdout in SunJDK Java 8. 
I am using -verbose:gc to enable GC logs and it is redirecting to stdout by default.
This can printed to a file using -Xloggc: argument.

But unable to print GC logs to stderr. Printing to stdout clutters my log file with GC allocation failure logs

Comment: `-Xloggc:stderr` seems like working for me

Answer (score 6):

For **Java 8** use

```
java -Xloggc:stderr
```

For **Java 9+** try using

```
java -Xlog:gc:stderr ...
```

Or for a higher log level

```
java -Xlog:gc=debug:stderr ...
```

Or for logging each garbage collection:

```
java -Xlog:gc*:stderr
```